evento js en input datetime-local con dispositivos móviles
Comparto un problema que me he encontrado y no soy capaz de solucionar.
Tengo un input datetime-local, que en pc funciona como espero con un evento change de javascript, pero en móviles el comportamiento es distinto.
En pc despliego el calendario, hago las modificaciones necesarias y cuando pulso Enter se activa el evento change.
En móviles despliego el calendario, y al modificar cualquier dato, de inmediato se dispara el evento change.
En móviles, dentro del calendario abajo a la derecha, se muestra la opción Ok, que entiendo es la clave de mi problema y no es compatible con el evento change.
Imagino que esa opción Ok equivale al Enter de un teclado.

He probado en distintos navegadores, tanto en pc como móviles, y el comportamiento siempre es el mismo, en pc el esperado y en móviles el comentado.
He intentado usar otro tipo de eventos, como keydown, input o click, y no han servido, de hecho, como ya he comentado, change cumple con lo esperado en pc.
En la web no he encontrado ninguna solución a mi problema, si varias recomendaciones a utilizar alternativas a input datetime, que en principio no valoro, ya que creo que mi problema es por desconocimiento y no un error que requiera una solución.
¿Cómo lo veis?.
Gracias.


document.addEventListener('change', e =>{
  if(e.target.matches('.fecha-tarea')){
    alert('llamo a la función modificar fecha con fetch')
  }
})
<input class="fecha-tarea" type="datetime-local" value="">




Por adivinar: Tu problema lo probaste solo en IOS ???

@Yussef gracias por contestar. Efectivamente solo IOS
